# Ext js resizable / collapsable panel resize problem

Tags: extjs

I have a layout with multiple resizable and collapsable panels like this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cbt

When i move the Left Panel and then the right one, the "statistik" panel will not strech correct.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statistik` will work correctly if you add `flex: 1` to neighbor panel (Move this first...) or you can try move panel up one level of nesting